# Drupal Site Crashing Constantly - Help Debugging

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

So we have a site running Drupal 7.41 on apache and it crashes constantly (multiple times a week). When it crashes we just restart the VM and the page start working again until the next crash. I installed New Relic in hope that it will help pin point what are some of the reasons why the site is crashing but I'm new to Drupal and maintaining it that I'm not sure where to start.

1. I've went to the 'Recent logs messages' section in Drupal but that doesn't seem to help. The last has been offline for some time since the last time I restarted it and the log messages don't show anything critical... just 'Notices':

[image: Drupal Screenshot]

2. On New Relic I can see that the CPU and Memory are maxed out precisely when the site crashes which gives the impression that this might be the error. Initially the site had 1GB of RAM and that was increased to 2GB when we thought this might be the problem. However, we see that it keeps maxing out so we're not sure if there really needs to be more RAM installed to avoid these crashes or if its just Apache (httpd) that tends to use that much RAM even if its not needed?

[image: New Relic - List of Processes]

[image: New Relic - Physical Memory]

[image: New Relic - CPU Usage]

As you can see, as I restart the server, everything seems to go back to normal.

Can anyone recommend a way to help me understand what might be the problem? Is it just that 2GB is not enough RAM? If so, how do I know how much RAM might be needed?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE#1:

I was reading this article: http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/drupal-performance-tuning-0 on some performing techniques on Apache specifically. The first thing they mentioned was to disable modules that you might not need in order to save memory and improve performance. Upon checking the Apache configuration directory (/etc/httpd/conf.d for CentOS) I found only a few modules enabled:

[image: Enables Modules Apache]

Should I disable any of those?

The second point they mentioned was to update some of Apache's Default Configuration Settings. I've set mines to these:

```
Timeout 30
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

UPDATE#2: MPM Settings Updated to these values:

```
StartServers       5
MinSpareServers    10
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       200
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
```

UPDATE#3: I increased the RAM to 4GB last night and so far the physical memory usage has been steady at ~2GB for the last 12 hours. It's a weekend so there's not much traffic to the site so let's see how this behaves in the next couple of days.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would duplicate the environment to try several things in a non-production environment. Here are some ideas of what I would do:

- Install the latest version of the Drupal core
- Have a look at the contributed modules you are using. Make sure you have the latest version installed.
- One by one, uninstall the contributed modules and verify whether the error keeps appearing. Try to do the same with the installed themes.
- I have had some problems with cron tasks. You can use the [Cron Debug](https://www.drupal.org/project/cron_debug) module to isolate the cron tasks running from each module and try to identify the problem.
- Just to discard an attack, use the [Hacked!](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module to confirm that the code you have installed in your server matches the code of the core and contributes modules available on Internet.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems here:

1. Your traffic/complexity of your site are not match for your hardware
2. Your drupal core using more resources than should

Your hardware looks good for average drupal site so i would go for other option. Also in your graphic you can see that CPU is 100% used before crash which means either your site is under spam attack or some module causing the problem.

- Go on admin/config/system/statistics and enable access log
- Go on /admin/reports/pages and /admin/reports/visitors and check number of hits per page/user on crash time.
- Go on admin/config/system/cron and disable cron to see if the problem
  is on some of the cron tasks.

Also it is the best practice to use latest module releases. You can easily see that on admin/reports/updates/update (you should have update manager module enabled for this). Make sure you backup potential customization on current modules before you update them.